# Custom tableviewCell content width is different from tableView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am using iPhone7 simulator.In my screen contain tableview with more than one different custom cell.

When my initial loading this screen my tableView width is 375 and cell.contentview width is 320.

But when I scroll this screen then tableview width is 375 and cell.contentview width is 375.

```
//Custom Cell class

@interface CustomTableViewCell ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblTitle;

@end

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

- (void)loadData:(NSString *)data
{
    self.lblTitle.text = data;
}

@end



//Viewcontroller class

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationItem.title = "profile"
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


    //tableview delegate method called from my datasource class like 

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return [self.datasource cellForSection:indexPath.section row:indexPath.row];
    }



 //Datasource class

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForSection:(NSInteger)section row:(NSInteger)row {

       CustomTableViewCell
 *cell = [self.view cellForReuseIdentifier:[CustomTableViewCell
 reuseIdentifierString]];

    [cell loadData:self.userRepository.currentUser.id];

    return cell;

}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: show your UI or related code

Comment: Please show the code where you use tableView delegates. Maybe you're making some UI changes or redraws or whatever else?

Answer (score 0):

it seems reusable cell problem. To fix this problem you should set condition of cell in section clearly. For example:

```
if section == 0 {
  return cellA;
} else if section == 1{
  return cellB;
} else {
  return cellB;
}
```

if my answer is not what you looking for, please add more additional information or code or screenshoot of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using constraints for the tableView and the actual sizing of the TableView is happening AFTER the data is loaded.
How you can check that:
print the size of the tableview right before `[self.tableView reloadData];`

How to fix that:
reload the data after the tableView is sized